# Using IFF in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a way to write an [iff](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iff#Conjunction) statement (i.e., if and only if) in Python?

I want to use it like in

```
for i in range(x)
    iff x%2==0 and x%i==0:
```

However, there isn't any `iff` statement in Python. Wikipedia defines the [truth table for iff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if#Definition) as this:

```
a |  b  |  iff a and b
-----------------------
T |  T  |      T
T |  F  |      F
F |  T  |      F
F |  F  |      T
```

How do I accomplish this in Python?

Comment: TIL the technical definition of IFF is the same as XNOR

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you look at the [truth table for IFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if#Definition), you can see that (p iff q) is true when both p and q are true or both are false. That's just the same as checking for equality, so in Python code you'd say:

```
if (x%2==0) == (x%i==0):
```

Answer (score 13):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if):

> Note that it is equivalent to that produced by the XNOR gate, and opposite to that produced by the XOR gate.

If that's what you're looking for you simply want this:

```
if not(x%2 == 0 ^ x%i == 0):
```

Answer (score 4):

The previous answers solve the problem.

As a note of clarification on this: the `if` statement is only accepting *one* input, not multiple. So when you do `if blah and bleh:`, it is equivalent to `if (blah and bleh):`. The expression `blah and bleh` is evaluated for truth value first, and that result is then fed to the `if` statement.

A truth table type of logic evaluation would require multiple inputs (`a` and `b`) instead of just one, but `if` doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [biconditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_biconditional) statement equivalence:

[image]

Answer (score -3):

I was just wondering the same. Here's a quick fix which worked:

```
def iff(a, b, c):
    if a:
        return b
    else:
        return c
```

Comment: That's [iif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IIf#Syntax) not iff